# how run gcc command from python script

Tags: python, gcc

I'm using this command from the terminal to create a text file that saves the errors without creating an output file.

```
 strace -e write -f gcc -I/home/user/my_test/headers -fsyntax-only test_file.c 2>log.txt
```

I was wondering if there is a python library that allow me to run the command above using a script. I'll appreciate any suggestion. thanks.

so I tried and it works as in the terminal

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["strace", "-e", "write", "-f", "gcc", "-I/home/user/my_test/headers", "-fsyntax-only", "test_file.c"])
```

but if I use this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["strace", "-e", "write", "-f", "gcc", "-I/home/user/my_test/headers", "-fsyntax-only", "test_file.c", "2>log.txt"])
```

it errors out. I think i'm missing something there.

```
write(2, "\33[01m\33[Kgcc:\33[m\33[K \33[01;31m\33[Ker"..., 81gcc: error: 2> log.txt: No such file or directory                           ) = 81                                                                
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: The ‘subprocess’ module should do it. 
Here’s a good article/tutorial that should give you all you need: https://realpython.com/python-subprocess/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How do I execute a program or call a system command?](/q/89228/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, it works with import os
cmd = 'strace -e write -f gcc -I/home/user/my_test/headers -fsyntax-only test_file.c 2>log.txt'
os.system(cmd) but not with subcall.  I guess that solves my problem.